# mysql city name from postalcode

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get some information about a user from a mysql database. I have a users table which contains columns like username, birthdate, profiletext, postalcode and so on, and then i have a table named cities which contains a postalcode column and a city_name column.

What i would like to do is get the cityname for the user from the postalcode.

The query looks like this at the moment:

```
$sql = ('
    SELECT
    username,
    birthdate,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age,
    profile_text,

    FROM users
    WHERE id = ?
');
```

My own guess is i should be using some kind of join, but i am not sure about that either.

Hope someone can help me.

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this the sql you looking for ?

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    users.birthdate,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,users.birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age,
    users.profile_text,
    cities.city_name,
    cities.postalcode
FROM users, cities
    WHERE id = ? and cities.postalcode = users.postalcode
```

Comment: Nope. In my users table i have a column called postalcode. In the cities table i have postalcode and city_name. What i would like is to get the city_name corresponding to the postalcode in the users table

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen so that query will return you results as you need.

Comment: Is that actually what it does? I will just test it!

Comment: it brings the city_name and postalcode (cities.city_name, cities.postalcode) from cities table, which postalcode (cities.postalcode) is equal to users postalcode (users.postalcode) value

Comment: i get an error when running that query:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users, cities WHERE id = '16' and cities.postalcode = users.postalcode' at line 8

Comment: sorry, there was one unneeded comma... fixed.

Comment: That did it, awesome! Didn't think it was that simple. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly straightforward join ... I don't have your exact fields, but something like this:

```
SELECT
    u.username,
    u.birthdate,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,u.birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age,
    u.profile_text,
    c.city

FROM users u, cities c
WHERE u.id = ? 
    and c.postal_code = u.postal_code
```